# Question on future tense

Tags: future-tense

“I will be leaving for France tomorrow”-1
“I will leave for France tomorrow”-2

What’s the difference in two sentences?, Which is statement is better?

Comment: Grammatically, both are correct. However, it is usual to go with the present progressive tense in such cases (that's when you have already planned on leaving for France.) Thus, _I am leaving for France tomorrow._

Comment: "I will be leaving for France tomorrow" could fit into a narrative even better than the standalone default 405662 adds. But "I will leave for France tomorrow" suggests decisiveness or a literary register.